# Ordered list item has number and square before it

Tags: html, css, styles, html-lists

I'm not finding a solution to this exact problem. My ordered list items have both a leading numeral and a black square. I want them to only have a leading numeral, and eliminate the black square. There may be another higher level style sheet controlling the look of the `li` , but I would like to override that with a local inline style.

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>Light all of the blah blah blah.</li>
  <li>Close the hood and blah blah blah.</li>
  <li>Turn off the  blah blah blah.</li>
  <li>Once the grill has  blah blah blah.</li>
</ol>
```

I've tried:

```
ol{
list-style-type:none;
list-style:none;
}
li{
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

...result: square only.

```
ol{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:none;
}
li{
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

...result: square only.

```
ol{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:decimal;
}
li{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:none;
}
```

...result: square only.

```
ol{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:decimal;
}
li{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:decimal;
}
```

...result: numeral and square.

I also tried a specific pseudoclass (I think that's the right term):

```
li.mine{
list-style-type:decimal;
list-style:decimal;
}
```

...etc., which. still produces a leading numeral and square.

```
<ol>
  <li class="maintenance">Light all of the blah blah blah.</li>
  <li class="maintenance">Close the hood and  blah blah blah.</li>
  <li class="maintenance">Turn off the  blah blah blah.</li>
  <li class="maintenance">Once the grill has  blah blah blah.</li>
</ol>
```

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, in the main stylesheet there is a `li:before { content: "■"; }`

I added `li:before{ content: "" }` to the local inline style, and that got rid of the square. Thanks to JoshC.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this.. there is some other HTML/CSS that is causing this. Perhaps it is a `:before` pseudo element causing this?

Comment: Try inspecting the element in the devloper tools to see which styles are being applied by which classes.  Maybe you have a style set as !important somewhere higher in the food chain.

Comment: @JoshC , you are exactly right. I just added a `li:before { content:""; }` and the square went away. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a `:before` pseudo element causing the square.

Either delete it, or add in the following:

```
li:before {
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: I will check this answer as the Correct Answer just as soon as SO lets me.